# How to generate pair in memory

Tags: java, memory

How do i duplicate a String vector with generate pairs?

for example, i got a vector with three words: Banana, Cat and Dog.
How do i duplicate this vector and words to another vector?

```
String playerOne = null;
    String playerTwo = null;
    int nrOfWords = 0;
    String[] allWords = new String []{"Banana", "Cat", "Book", "Sandwich", "Strawberry", "Milk", "Card", "Computer", "Science", "Java", "Math", "Physics", "Materials", "Phone", "Pencil", "Tv", "Clock", "Shoes", "Jacket", "Gloves"};
    String [] pair = null;
    boolean gameIsOver = false;


    System.out.print("How many words do you want?(max 20); ");
    nrOfWords = in.nextInt();
    while(nrOfWords < 1 || nrOfWords > 20)
    {
        if( nrOfWords > 20)
        {
            System.out.print("You have choosen more than 20 words. Please try again:");
            nrOfWords = in.nextInt();
        }
        if(nrOfWords < 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Error, not a vaild number. Plese Try again.");
            nrOfWords = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    //Create a duplicate of allWords vector with generatePairs.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a while loop to create a random number between 0 and 20:

```
nrOfWords = in.nextInt(20/*max number*/);
```

Now you'll count up till nrOfWords and add them at an offset in String[] pair;

```
pair = new String[nrOfWords]; //be sure to initalize or you'll get a NullPointerException
int index = 0; //set up index var
for(int counter=0;counter!=nrOfWords;counter++) {
    pair[index] = allWords[index];
    //or pick a random word:
    //pair[index] = allWords[in.nextInt(allWords.length)];
}
```